# Clear Guarded Doubly Linked List in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, doubly-linked-list

I'm currently learning for a CS exam and the following question came to my mind: If I have a doubly linked list with two fields (one head-guard and tail-guard) and I want to clear the list (make it empty). Will it be enough to set the tail node to be the `next`-element after my head and vice versa (`previous`-node of tail is head). Will the garbage collection delete the elements between these two (the elements reference each other, but no reference from the outside to a node of this 'block' exists?

To make this a little clearer: If I have this:
`|HEAD| <--> |node_01| <--> | . . .| <--> |node_n| <--> |TAIL|`

And I change the `next`/`previous` node of the head and tail to this:
`|HEAD| <--> |Tail|`
Will Java delete the`node_01 - node_n` (notice the singly arrows):
`|HEAD| <-- |node_01| <--> | . . . | <--> |node_n| --> |TAIL|`

They all reference each other, but no reference from *outside* exists - ergo I can't reach them. Or is this a memory leak?

Comment: If there are really no references to these dangling nodes, then I expect the garbage collector will delete them at the next scheduled collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular example, the GC **will** clear the list completely.
This is because they are not reachable from the graph to the root objects of the application object graph.

In the implementation of [`clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear()) you can observe that every object is set to `null` as well, this is to prevent any memory leaks if some object is referencing it. But in your case you specifically said that this can't occur.

The implementation of `clear` for reference:

```
/**
 * Removes all of the elements from this list.
 */
public void clear() {
    Entry<E> e = header.next;
    while (e != header) {
        Entry<E> next = e.next;
        e.next = e.previous = null;
        e.element = null;
        e = next;
    }
    header.next = header.previous = header;
    size = 0;
modCount++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you really much! I was just thinking, that it's an pretty elegant solution to clear the list even though it's probably a more secure way to do it like this.

Comment: Thank you for the link to `JCF`'s implementation as well!